# XAML designer is not loading in the WPF after adding a custom control, but is working fine in runtime in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2019, WPF xaml designer is not loading in the design time showing as **invalid markup** but while building the project and in runtime the application is running along with the custom control works fine

In the design time is giving error as **Error XDG0008 The name CustomControl does not exist in the namespace clr-namespace:xxxx.xxxx.xxx;assembly=xxx**

**Visual Studio 2019 designer error:**
[image]

Comment: Try to clean the Solution and rebuild it.
If it does not help, then exit the Studio and delete all folders (including subfolders) from the Solutions folder: ".vs" (it may be hidden, but you need to find and delete), "bin", "obj", "packages" .
Then open the Solution again in Studio and rebuild it again.
If it does not help, then it is already necessary to look more deeply at the entire Solution.

Comment: Not working this i have tried @EldHasp

Comment: If this does not help, then you need to check the implementation code.
Perhaps in it you want to use some data that does not exist at design time and an exception is thrown.
Lay out the entire code of your CustomControl (including its theme).

Comment: But the same designer is coming in Visual studio 2017

Comment: Maybe there is some error in the settings of the Studio itself.
Anything can be.
Therefore, I am writing so that you give the complete code so that I can check it on my computer.